# Active Admin keep ask me to login after redirect to some Show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, authentication, activeadmin

I want to redirect to some Active Admin show page after a controller have done it's work

```
redirect_to admin_some_path(some)
```

I have logged in to an admin account but Active Admin keep show login page before redirect to the page.

What should I do?

Comment: Do `rake routes` to know the available routes.

Comment: routes are correct. The problem is something like CSRF token but i have no idea how to manage it.